# Get file path from FTPService for use in RoutingEngine

Tags: intersystems-ensemble

I have a service of class `EnsLib.HL7.Service.FTPService` that picks up files from multiple subfolders and sends them to an `EnsLib.HL7.MsgRouter.RoutingEngine`.   What I want to do is somehow capture the subfolder as a variable for use in the routing rules.  Is this possible?

Let's say I have the following files and directory structure on my FTP Server

> /incoming/green/apple.dat
>
> /incoming/yellow/banana.dat

I want the Routing Rule to be able to send anything that came from the /green/ folder to one operation and from /yellow/ to another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a message viewer, you can trace any messages. Where you can see any message properties, and one of them is `Source`. Text in this property looks like:

```
Source  apple.dat via FTP localhost:21 path '/incoming/green/'
```

So with all of this data, you can create a rule by this property in a Rule editor[image]

Comment: You are awesome!  I wish I could upvote more than once.  Instead, I'll ask a followup question :)