# HERE-sdk.aar missing the RoutingEngine class

Tags: android, here-api, aar, here-android, here-routing

I'm trying to use the HERE SDK FOR ANDROID (PREMIUM EDITION) SDK version 3.18.3 for routing/directions. I am using [this method](https://github.com/heremaps/here-sdk-examples/blob/master/examples/latest/explore/android/Routing/app/src/main/java/com/here/routing/RoutingExample.java) to get a route. I can not get the RoutingEngine class to import from the HERE-sdk.aar I did doublecheck the file, RoutingEngine is not within the HERE-sdk.aar After that I tried to use the docs from HERE.com but they also use the RoutingEngine. Other aspects of the .aar file work properly. What can I do to get around this?

I have searched on SO here are other questions that didn't help. [redownloading sdk didn't resolve issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43171179/android-here-maps-classes-missing).  I came across this [Get file path from FTPService for use in RoutingEngine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34795551/get-file-path-from-ftpservice-for-use-in-routingengine)
 this was for another system.

What else can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on whether you want to use the older 3.x based *Premium Edition* or the new 4.x *Navigate Edition* or *Explore Edition*. They share a completely new technology stack and are not compatible with the older 3.x based *Premium Edition*.

The `RoutingEngine` is only part of the new editions. And your example code link is pointing to the 4.x based editions.

If you still want to use the [Premium Edition](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/3.18/dev_guide/topics/overview.html), use these [example apps](https://github.com/heremaps/here-android-sdk-examples). They are hosted on a different GitHub repo, including [this](https://github.com/heremaps/here-android-sdk-examples/blob/master/routing/app/src/main/java/com/here/android/example/routing/MapFragmentView.java) routing example. The code base is very different and thus, no `RoutingEngine` is available for the 3.x editions.

For the new 4.x editions, [Explore Edition](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-sdk-explore) or [Navigate Edition](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-sdk-navigate), you can find the fitting example apps [here](https://github.com/heremaps/here-sdk-examples), which is where your above link is coming from.

Comment: I'm needing the turn by turn directions so I will need the Navigate Edition, I noticed at the bottom of the Navigate Edition page it states this: For now, the Navigate Edition is only available upon request. Please contact us to receive access including a set of evaluation credentials. The HERE SDK package for the Navigate Edition is available on the HERE platform portal. Does  this mean that the Navigate Edition is not covered under the freemium edition? That it is a premium only for the minimum $49/month?

Comment: The Navigate Edition is not covered within the Pro plan. You can see an overview here: https://developer.here.com/plan-features   I suggest that you get in contact with us and we discuss the possibilities directly: https://developer.here.com/help?form_id=2227&form_category=contact-us&detailed_source=cms.developer.here.com%2Fhelp

Comment: The Navigate Edition is downloadable from here: https://platform.here.com/sdk - but for the credentials you would still need to contact HERE. I heard it's planned that this will be changed in the future, so that a developer can create them on the portal as self-service - similar to the other editions. But since the Navigate Edition has different plan details, this is not yet available.

Comment: Thank you, I've started using the HERE SDK for Android (Premium Edition) 3.18 for the turn by turn navigation. It seems to.domjust what I need for it.